# Shadow behind a cardview using xml

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I am trying to make a circular image view with a shadow behind. I have searched many places but everywhere either it is using java or any other method, but none of them seems to work for me. Is there a way to do so using xml. Please help I am stuck.

This is my image view:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:tint="#fff"
            android:padding="12dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_shape"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/food"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/price" />
```

And here is my shape from drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="1dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="2.5"
android:useLevel="false" >

<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
<solid
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<padding
    android:left="6dp"
    android:top="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:bottom="6dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: You can use android:elevation attribute

Comment: Tried that, Not working..

Comment: What kind of shadow you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:elevation` in image view. 
Depending on value shadow will cange.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

> card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

to your **CardView**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:elevation` attribute to achieve what you want.

You may read more about evevations in Android here.
https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html